# How to use firebase rule to check is user group array and record group array intersect

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a list of records in firebase which will have a group property with zero or more groups on it.  I also have the firebase auth object which will also have zero or more groups on it as well.  I would like to set up a .read firebase rule for my records that will check if the two have at lease one group that exists in both lists.

Put another way I have a user that has an array of groups that have been assigned to it.  I have some records that also has some list of groups on them that specify what groups the user must have to access them.  If the logged in user tries to access the record, I want to make sure that the user has at least one group that the record requires.

On the client I would do something like `_.intersect(userGroups, recordGroups).length > 0`

I'm not sure how I would do this in a firebase rule expression.  It would be cool if it worked something like this.

Record:

```
{
  someData: "test"
  groups: ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

Firebase Auth Object:

```
{
  userName: "Bob",
  groups: ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

Rule Data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "records": {
      "$recordId": {
        ".read": "data.child('groups').intersectsWith(auth.groups)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

**Update:**
I think that if hasChildren() used || instead of && I could put the group names in they key position and check for their existence this way.  Something like `"data.child('groups').hasChildren(auth.groups, 'or')"`

Where Record:

```
{
  someData: "test"
  groups: {
    'foo': '',
    'bar': ''
  }
}
```

**Update2:**
Based off Kato's comment & link I realize that even if hasChildren could do OR it still wouldn't work quite right.  Requests for individual records would work but requests for all records would error if the current user didn't have access to every record.

It is still not clear how you would structure data to make this work.  If a record could belong to many groups how would that work?  This is a very common scenario(basically how linux group permissions work) so I can't be the only one trying to do this.  Anyone have any ideas/examples of how to accomplish this in firebase?

Comment: Firebase security rules [can't be used as filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter). You'll probably want to store your records by group if that's how they are to be retrieved.

Comment: Not sure how that would work.  Users belong to many groups and records belong to many groups.  As long as they both have a group in common access should be provided.

Comment: Any update to this? I have a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078703/proper-firebase-security-rules-for-implementing-rbac)

Comment: I'm trying to solve the exactly same problem. @yodaisgreen did you find a solution/workaround for it ?

Comment: It has been a year ago,.. do you still looking for an answer for this question? @yodaisgreen

Comment: Not really.  I'm using mongodb now.  FB is cool but it got to be too frustrating.  @NikAhmadZainalddin

Answer (score 1):

At the current moment, I believe it's impossible. There's a limited number of variables, methods, and operators allowed, listed here:

[Firebase Security Rules API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/)

Since function definitions are not allowed in the rules, you can't do anything fancy like call array.some(callback) on an array to do the matching yourself.

You have three options that I know of:

1) Copy data so you don't need to do the check. This is what I did in my project: I wanted some user data (names) available to users that shared a network in their network lists. Originally I wanted to check both member's network lists to see if there was at least one match. Eventually I realized it would be easier to just save each user's name as part of the network data so there wouldn't have to be a user look up requiring this odd permissions. I don't know enough about your data to suggest what you need to copy.

2) Use strings instead of arrays. You can turn one string into a regex (or just save it in regex format) and use it to search the other string for a match.[Firebase DB Regex Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex)

3) If you have enough weird cases like this, actually run a server that validates the request in a custom fashion. In the DB, just allow permissions to your server. You could use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) or roll your own server that uses the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: However, it seems that you can't use a string stored in the DB as a regexp, right? I think the regexp has to be written beforehand in the rules

Comment: Yeah. You can't use `matches()` rule with a regex pattern string stored in the database. It will say `matches() expects a regular expression literal argument.`.

Comment: Hey @ansorensen, could you get a little bit deeper in the third option? I could not find any information about running your own rules server. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, there's another possibility: to use Firestore to deliver your content, possibly in sync with the Realtime Database.

In Firestore, you can create rules like this:

```
function hasAccessTo(permissionList) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/permissions/$(request.auth.uid))
      .data.userPermissions.keys().hasAny(permissionList)
}

match /content/{itemId} {
  allow read: if hasAccessTo(resource.data.permissions.keys());
}
```

The following data would allow a read of $CONTENTID by $UID, because the user permissions set intersects with the possible permissions required to access the content (with `access123`). My scenario is that a piece of content can be unlocked by multiple In-App Purchases.

```
{
  permissions: { 
    $UID: { userPermissions: { access123:true, access456:true } },
    ...
  },
  content: { 
    $CONTENTID: { ..., permissions: { access123, access789 } },
    ...
  }
}
```

For a progressive migration, you can keep data in sync between the Realtime Database and Firestore by using a one-way Cloud Function like this for example:

```
exports.fsyncContent = functions.database
  .ref("/content/{itemId}")
  .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
    const item = snapshot.after.val();
    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("content")
      .doc(context.params.itemId)
      .set(item);
  });
```